# easy_install in windows XP with error "Not a recognized archive type"

Tags: python, windows-xp, gzip, easy-install

This error "**Not a recognized archive type**" happens on one Windows XP machine but Never happen on another one. It's so weird!

My python is **2.5**, did I miss something in my windows?

Comment: What command are you running across this with? More information needed.  `easy_install foo`, `easy_install`, `easy_install --something -or other`, etc.?

Comment: @Chris, for example, I was running easy_install pysqlite

Answer (score 6):

there is a good chance you have a file or directory in your path that has the same name with the package you are trying to install, like:

```
easy_install ali    
# Processing ali
# error: Not a recognized archive type: ali
```

this is because I have an ./ali in the same directory or on the path that I am running the easy_install command from

Comment: you have a file or directory in your path that has the same name +1

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me when I've accidentally renamed the setuptools egg after or during downloading ... Downloading and reinstalling has always fixed it. :)

Instructions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: Thanks, but I clean up setuptools and reinstalled. still the same thing.